# Wpf listview item object doubleclick

Tags: wpf, listview, double-click

I have a list of objects that get dynamically created when the window opens. For instance:

```
//Set content for listview sentitems
inbox.ItemsSource = from email in _dataDC.emails
                    where email.from == _username
                    orderby email.time descending
                    select email;
```

My xaml:

```
<TabItem Header="Inbox" Height="30">
    <TabItem.Content>
        <ListView Name="inbox" BorderThickness="2" Margin="5,0,-5,0">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Van" Width="70" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding from}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Onderwerp" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding subject}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Op" Width="130" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding time}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </TabItem.Content>
</TabItem>
```

When an item in the list is doubleclicked, I simply want to open a new window. Object gets passed to the new window, where I do something with it. Any simple solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out...

XAML

```
<ListView  Name="inbox" BorderThickness="2" Margin="5,0,-5,0" MouseDoubleClick="inbox_OnMouseDoubleClick">
```

C#

```
private void inbox_OnMouseDoubleClick(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // Assumes your NewWindow class has a constuctor that takes the Email type.
    NewWindow window = new NewWindow((Email)inbox.SelectedItem);
    window.Show();
}
```

Comment: What is different here from the answer i posted?

Answer (score 2):

Use ListView's  MouseDoubleClick.

**XAML:**

```
<ListView Name="inbox" BorderThickness="2" Margin="5,0,-5,0" MouseDoubleClick="ListView_MouseDoubleClick">
```

**Code Behind:**

```
private void ListView_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
       var item = (sender as ListView).SelectedItem;
        if (item != null)
        {
            //use the item here and pass to the new window
            NewModal s = new NewModal(Email)item);
        }
}
```

Comment: This is a single click though, no? It would have to be a double click :3

Comment: @user3227070 Yes you can have

Comment: I'm sorry, I get an error saying that it cannot convert type from object to email. I'll edit my question, one sec

Comment: Cast `item` to the Email type in calling NewModal constructor. Eg, `NewModal s = new NewModal((Email)item);`

Comment: @user3227070 As gengis mentioned you need to cast